# Cannot install HelloCardboard into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, virtual-reality, google-vr

Hi i'm looking to develop my first mobile vr game and I've been following a few tutorials to get started with this in Unity.

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart

All of these explain how you need to install a specific package via the package manager:
https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin.git

When I add this via the package manager using the Git URL option I just get the error

> [Package Manager Window] Error adding package:
> https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin.git.
> UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at
> /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:327)

Is there something I'm missing? is there some kind of setting or something? All the tutorials literally just add the URl and it works but mine just wont seem to.

I'm using the latest version of unity and running it on a macbook pro if that has any relevance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have [Git](https://git-scm.com/) installed on your PC which is a [requirement](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html) to be able to install git packages by git URL in the Package Manager –

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a brand new macbook so i had yet to do all the final set ups. Running git --version in my terminal to check what was installed showed it was a case of just accepting the terms and conditions of the newly installed xcode which i had yet to open....

With those accepted Unity now allows me to install git url's via the package manager.